# How to show the deployed version of my application in angular app using jenkins and docker

Tags: python, angular, docker, jenkins

I have an angular app calling Python (FastAPI) apis. I use Jenkins for building docker image and pushing to server.
jenkins file in angular project: (my current version here is 0.3)

```
pipeline {
    agent any
  stages {
    stage('Build') {
        steps {
          sh 'docker build -t server.firm.local/firm/proj.ui:0.3 -f ./build/Dockerfile .'
        }
    }
    stage('Push') {
       steps {
          sh 'docker push server.firm.local/firm/proj.ui:0.3'
      }
    }
  }
}
```

jenkins file in python:(my current version here is 0.2)

```
pipeline {
    agent any
    stages {
        stage('Build UI') {
            steps {
                build(job: 'PROJECT/develop')
            }
        }
        stage('Build base image') {
            steps {
                sh 'docker build -t py3_9_ubi8_ora:0.0.1 -f OS/Dockerfile .'
            }
        }
        stage('Build Project') {
            steps {
                sh 'export APP_VERSION=$APP_VERSION && docker build -t server.firm.local/firm/proj:0.2 -f build/Dockerfile .'
            }
        }
        stage('Push Project') {
            steps {
                sh 'docker push server.firm.local/firm/proj:0.2'
            }
        }
    }
}
```

the dockerfile in the api copies the image of the angular app and the deployment works perfect.
I am new to jenkins and docker and I don't know how to export both versions, 0.3 for UI and 0.2 for api so users can see them on screen.

I tried to create an env variable but I am not sure that's working

```
pipeline {
    agent any

    environment{
        APP_VERSION = '0.4'
    }

    stages {
        stage('Build UI') {
            steps {
                build(job: 'PROJECT/develop')
            }
        }
        stage('Build base image') {
            steps {
                sh 'docker build -t py3_9_ubi8_ora:0.0.1 -f OS/Dockerfile .'
            }
        }
        stage('Build Project') {
            steps {
                sh 'export APP_VERSION=$APP_VERSION && docker build -t server.firm.local/firm/proj:${APP_VERSION} -f build/Dockerfile .'
            }
        }
        stage('Push Project') {
            steps {
                sh 'docker push server.firm.local/firm/proj:${APP_VERSION}'
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue with environments variables is that your front will depend on your infrastructure, and you may also get complications during local development.

An other way to retrieve variables in the front:

- Add a script in your jenkins/docker to edit a config file (for example a configuration.json file) with the wanted data in the /assets folder of your angular application. You can use a template too
- In the angular app, create an identical local config file for local development. This file would be overridden by the script when deploying
- In the mains.ts of your application, add some treatment to fetch the config file and map its content to a configuration object and a reusable service. For example:

```js
    fetch("/assets/configuration.json")
      .then((response) => response.json())
      .then((config) => {
        platformBrowser([
          { provide: ConfigurationService, useValue: new ConfigurationService(config) },
        ])
          .bootstrapModule(AppModule)
          .catch((err) => console.error(err));
      });
```

This operation is launched at app startup

- In the angular app, the service can be used to get and display config data everywhere in the app
- You can also see the current config file content, opening `<app-url>/assets/configuration.json` url in a browser